# Title с NavigationDrawer вытаскивается с не тем id

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

у меня navigation drawer, в который я динамически добавляю категории. у каждой категории есть id, которые приходят с сервера. Мне нужно вытащить тайтлы категории, когда я на нее кликаю. вытаскивать то я вытаскиваю, но при этом отображается совсем другой тайтл с совсем другим id.

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    ...
    else {
        title = String.valueOf(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(id).getTitle());
        NewsFrag fragment = NewsFrag.newInstance(id, null, title);
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
```

То есть я кликаю на одну и категорий. ее айди с сервера равно 5, тайтл ее "Яблоко". А в итоге получаю на след шаге айди 6 и тайтл "Апельсин". Где может меняется этот айди. Что я упустил? Примерно, есть идея, что это из-за того, что получаю какой-то айди, а работает он уже с айди элемента, как он расположен в  самой системе. Но как это обойти не знаю. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где и как вы тайтл смотрите? И вообще - мало инфы. В приведённом коде ошибки нет.

Comment: id элемента на сервере скорее всего отличается от id  у вас. Для того, чтобы помочь вам найти уточните, как формируются, откуда загружаются ваши элементы навигации.